# How do I stop a CSS animation on a hyperlink after the link is visited?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to use CSS animations to make a hyperlink blink until it has been visited. However, my current code doesn't work – it continues blinking even after it is clicked.

How can I cause the link to stop blinking after it has been visited?

My CSS:

```
blink {
    -webkit-animation: 0.5s linear infinite condemned_blink_effect; 
    animation: 1.5s linear infinite condemned_blink_effect;
}

@-webkit-keyframes condemned_blink_effect { 
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    50% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

@keyframes condemned_blink_effect {
    0% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    50% {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    100% {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}

blink:visited{
    -webkit-animation: none;
    animation: none;
}
```

My PHP code that generates the link HTML is:

```php
echo "<td width='150'><a href='dispdata.php?id=" . $dataReturn->dataID . "'><blink>View </a><blink></td> ";
```

Comment: Only show the rendered HTML.

Comment: I think the reason it keeps blinking is that you have html in your code that tells it to. ( <blink></blink>). Also, the tags are misplaced, (i.e., <a><blink></a></blink>). Should be (<a><blink></blink></a>)

Comment: @nocturns2 ya the link is wriiten as follows echo "<td width='150'><a href='dispdata.php?id=".$dataReturn- 
>dataID."'><blink>View </a><blink></td> ";

Comment: `<td width='150'><a href='dispdata.php?id=".$dataReturn- >dataID."'><blink>View </a><blink></td>` ||| Close the `<blink>` move `</blink>` inside the `<a>`

Comment: since you're echo'ing the line of html, you could echo a conditional code without the blink tag in the html.

Comment: Normally, when a link is clicked, it sends the user to somewhere else (i.e., a different page, handler or something). If it's going to stay on the same page, then your php should be able to determine if the link was clicked via a session variable or some other method. So, when it redraws the page it won't contain the <blink> tags.

Answer (score 2):

The `<blink>` element was never part of the HTML standard and was a joke added in a version of Netscape at some point. Modern browsers don't support this element at all because everyone agrees blinking elements are annoying. [See more details here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink)

You can still produce a blinking effect through CSS like you tried, but your selectors are incorrect. `:visited` can only apply to links (`<a>` elements) but you wrote `blink:visited`. That won't work, as this means "select all `<blink>` elements that are also visited `<a>` elements". An element can't be both, so the selector never works.

Finally, the styles that can be set on a `:visited` selector are limited because of the potential security risks. One could abuse this selector to steal a user's browsing history. [See more details here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) If you want to make a specific link open a page in a new tab and then stop blinking, you will need JavaScript.

For example, you could use a `blinking` CSS class to make the link blink and then remove the class from the element when it is clicked. In this code, I put the blinking effect on a nested `<span>` element because otherwise you wouldn't be able to click the link while it is hidden by the animation.

Again, this is not something I would recommend using at all as it will annoy your users.

```js
function stopBlinking(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.remove("blinking");
}

const blinking = document.querySelectorAll(".blinking");
for (link of blinking) {
  link.addEventListener("click", stopBlinking);
}
```

```css
.blinking span {
  -webkit-animation: 0.5s linear infinite condemned_blink_effect; 
  animation: 1.5s linear infinite condemned_blink_effect;
}

@-webkit-keyframes condemned_blink_effect { 
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@keyframes condemned_blink_effect {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="blinking"><span>Sample link</span></a><br>
<a href="#" class="blinking"><span>Sample link</span></a><br>
<a href="#" class="blinking"><span>Sample link</span></a>
```